# VBA UserForm Get Filename

Tags: excel, get, filenames, userform, vba

I have constructed a UserForm that consists of 2 CommandButtons, each of which contains a Picture. The user is asked to select one of the two CommandButtons. I would like the filename of the picture selected to be copied to a cell in a worksheet. At the moment I can't figure out how to get the filename of the picture and so I have manually inserted the filename for each CommandButton, as such:

```
Private Sub cmdQ2Opt1_Click()
    Worksheets("UserQuestionnaire").Range("C4").Value = "242.216.490"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdQ2Opt2_Click()
    Worksheets("UserQuestionnaire").Range("C4").Value = "354.129.401"
End Sub
```

How can I code this so that VBA automatically copies the picture's filename?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the picture in the *Forms Designer* the path is not stored as the image is subsequently loaded from storage within the workbook itself.

To persist the path you would load at runtime:

```
dim path As string
path = "C:\...\foo.jpg"
set commandbutton1.Picture = loadpicture(path)
```

You can then store the path in the buttons `Tag` property:

```
commandbutton1.Tag = path
```

Then read it back when its clicked:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UserQuestionnaire").Range("C4").Value = commandbutton1.Tag
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I am slightly new to VBA so would you mind please clarifying what you mean by 'load at runtime'? Would I adapt this code into a Class Module, Module or UserForm code as a regular Private Sub?

Comment: I mean if you put a picture in a button by browsing to an image file in the buttons property window you cannot then get its path back for later use elsewhere, so instead you load the picture into the button when you need it (or in the userform's initialize event)

Comment: Understood. Thank you. Is there a way to do the same without referring to a file path and instead embedding the picture in the file? I worry that referring to a specific path will mean that the buttons won't work when I send the file on to others who have no access to the path.

Comment: What is it you want to do with the picture?

Comment: I am creating a form whereby users are asked to 'vote' for their preferred picture, and this result is recorded in a worksheet. As I will be sending the file to others, I would like the images embedded in the file and not saved separately in a local directory.

Comment: If you add the image via the buttons "picture" entry in its properties window it will be embedded in the workbook as you were originally doing, however you will not then be able to retrieve the path as you originally wanted.