# Show picture/image from userform in print header, VBA MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I am making a template and thought to store our logo.jpg inside a userform. Then I'll call this userform and insert the logo in the print header for each "macro activated" print.

So far I have managed to print the image only as numbers. Bits and bytes probably(?). I might be missing some conversion of the picture before printing:

```
FilePageSetupHeader Alignment:=pjLeft, Text:="&P" & UserForm1.Image1.Picture & " "
```

This prints as: `1-670746914` in the top left header.

What am I missing?

The syntax I found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-filepagesetupheader-method-project) gives the following parameters for inserting a picture:

  &;P""path""

  Inserts the specified image. An example would be &;P"" [My Documents] \Image.gif"". The term [My Documents] represents the full path to your My Documents folder.

My code makes a copy of the current view, make changes to the view settings, headers etc, before exporting to PDF and deleting the view again.

Answer (score 1):

`UserForm1.Image1.Picture` is a picture ***object***, not the path to the original source file. Once a picture is loaded into an image control, it is embedded and its original path is not stored.

Store the path the the picture so that you can reference it later (e.g. using the `Tag` property of the Image control). See [Stack Overflow: VBA UserForm Get Filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873268/vba-userform-get-filename) for more details. (FYI: Excel and Project use the same UserForm object, so this is applicable.)

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. I was able to reproduce and get the image in the header with the `Tag` property. But it is essentially the same as typing the full path to the image.<br> Like this  `"&P""[My Documents] \Image.gif""`. If the user don't have this file on his hard drive in addition to the .mpp file, it wont show. I was more in the business of doing something like [this (link)](https://danny.fyi/embedding-and-accessing-a-file-in-excel-with-vba-and-ole-objects-4d4e7863cfff). But it refers too much to Excel VBA that don't exist in Project.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on saving the logo inside the Project file itself.

Instead I check if the logo exists inside `"C:\CompanyLogo"`, if does not, create that direcotry and download it from imgur.